# How to safely make a HTTP GET request to an API that handles failure

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my website I want to make a HTTP GET request using jQuery to a 3rd party API.
If the API is down I want to handle it gracefully.

Basically my page will run fine without the result of the API response, but if it is successful then I will modify some DOM element on my page.

Is there a way to do this natively with jquery to handle failure or timeout?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error-handler in the ajax request. Watch my snippet:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",  
    url: "YOURURLHERE",
    success: function(data){  
        // Do stuff with the data & modify your dom
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        // Error 
    }       
});
```